# Tricks on how to execute string inside a function in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, function, procedure

Procedure FunctionX, Line 345

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a
>   function.

I get the above error when I execute a dynamic statement inside a function in SQL Server 2012.
Is there a workaround for this? Any tricks?

PS: The sproc (stored procedure) is much too lengthy for its body to be inserted as-is inside the function.

```
DECLARE @execsql NVARCHAR(2000)
Set @execsql = 'INSERT INTO @TABLE1 EXEC SPROC1 ' + @ID_COMPANY + ',' + @ID_COUNTRY 
exec (@execsql)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Also, I need to be able to delete inside the function as well. I know this contradicts the definition of functions but I am wondering if there are some tricks that can be used

Comment: The bigger question is why do you think you need to use a function here? A function is designed to return a single value, it is not a stored procedure which is what you are describing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No there are no tricks, see **[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#UDF)**

> ## Dynamic SQL in User-Defined Functions
>
> **This is very simple: you cannot use dynamic SQL from used-defined
> functions written in T-SQL**. This is because you are not permitted to do
> anything in a UDF that could change the database state (as the UDF may
> be invoked as part of a query). Since you can do anything from dynamic
> SQL, including updates, it is obvious why dynamic SQL is not
> permitted.
>
> I've seen more than one post on the newsgroups where people have been
> banging their head against this. But if you want to use dynamic SQL in
> a UDF, back out and redo your design. You have hit a roadblock, and in
> SQL 2000 there is no way out.
>
> In SQL 2005 and later, you could implement your function as a CLR
> function. Recall that all data access from the CLR is dynamic SQL.
> (You are safe-guarded, so that if you perform an update operation from
> your function, you will get caught.) A word of warning though: data
> access from scalar UDFs can often give performance problems. If you
> say
>
> SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE dbo.MyUdf(somecol) = @value
>
> and MyUdf performs data access, you have more or less created a hidden
> cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem with dynamic OPENQUERY statements inside a multi-line table-valued function. SQL Server is trying to prevent users with only db_datareader access, who can select from these functions, from performing SQL injections. Long story short, remove as many single quotes as you can and find a way to do the same thing without using EXEC.
Instead of doing this:

```
Set @execsql = 'INSERT INTO @TABLE1 EXEC SPROC1 ' + @ID_COMPANY + ',' + @ID_COUNTRY
```

Do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT *
FROM --some unfiltered version of the table your stored procedure uses
WHERE company = @ID_COMPANY
AND country = @ID_COUNTRY
```

Since you're calling a function from a stored procedure you can already be sure the table will be up to date. In my case, I was able to have a job refresh the function's underlying table using the stored procedure once every morning. You could also use a trigger to do that.