# How to create a function to get error number of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2014

When I execute this query `select 1/0`  in sql server, it will show this Message:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Divide by zero error encountered.

I need a function to get Number of error. for this example output of my function should be `8134`

how can I create this function to get my required result?

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetErrorNumber 
(
    @command NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    --function Body
END
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175069.aspx

Comment: @Behnam You are going to pass your query to this function, or just the error message?

Comment: @Behnam is this a homework or something real?

Comment: It's completely real and i need it for my program

Comment: Are you trying to identify all occurrences of 0 in the divisor or are you trying to stop your software failing when it encounters a divisor of 0?

Comment: @Behnam then you are doing something wrong. Right answer is in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to pass the error message to function, then try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fun_GetErrorNumber
(
    @command NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN CAST(SUBSTRING(@q,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@q),PATINDEX('%,%',@q)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@q)) AS INT)
END
```

But if you want to pass the query to function, you should take note that executing command inside Function is not valid and you need to use stored procedure instead. Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Pro_Execute
(
  @command NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  @num INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@command);
        SET @num = 0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @num = ERROR_NUMBER();
    END CATCH;

END;
```

And call it like this:

```
DECLARE @res INT
EXEC  Pro_Execute 'Select 1/0' ,@num = @res output
SELECT @res
```

The above `SP` will get the command and execute it. If non-fatal error occurred while executing the command, error number will be returned.

Reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx) may help you decorate your solution in better way

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to parse the error message and get the number between `Msg` and `,`.

This seems like a simple string manipulation to me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetErrorNumber 
(
    @command nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@command, 5, CHARINDEX(',', @command, 5) - 5) as int)
END
```

Though I do agree with juergen d - simply using the built in `ERROR_NUMBER()` seems better in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32868841/4519059), You can't.

When you want to check your command you need to **execute** that command that it is impossible in body of a function.